# Next Auth error in middleware. Module parse failed: Identifier 'NextResponse' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I did authorization using next auth, everything is exactly the same as in the documentation and video. When I wanted to make middleware in next js, nothing happened at first, but when I add:

`export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";`

or add withAuth(), I get an error:

./node_modules/next-auth/next/middleware.js
Module parse failed: Identifier 'NextResponse' has already been declared (3:6)
| "use strict";
| const NextResponse = require("next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response").NextResponse;

> const NextResponse = require("next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response").NextResponse;
> | var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");
> | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK8nb.png)

I wanted to make a middleware in which I will redirect the user depending on the session in the next auth.